# Comparing big files

Tags: linux, file, assembly, diff

So I've got really big `.bin` files with `bytes` written in them. They have `96-bit` numbers written in them as `two's complement` numbers (still no ASCII, only bytes). Now I have to write an assembly program to sort the numbers in this files and save it to another file (don't ask why, `assembly` class). I've done it for a file with `32k` numbers, like this:

```
./main < inSort32Kx96b.bin > XD.bin
diff outSort32Kx96b.bin XD.bin
```

The file `outSort32Kx96b.bin` is given to me by my teacher. So now `diff` doesn't output anything, they are identical (I can check that with `hexdump` or `mcview`). But I got another file `inSort1Kx96b.bin`. And I also sort it. But then diff says:

```
Binary files outSort1Kx96b.bin and XD.bin differ
```

@Edit:

`cmp` gave the number of byte where those 2 files differ. Now I can see the difference:

[image]

So the difference appears from `0x000017C0`. Then I don't know now. If they are written as `two's complement` numbers in `little endian` order, then which one is bigger, f.e

```
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 00
```

or

```
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 7F  00 00 00 00
```

?

Comment: Off topic here, and operating system specific. On Linux use [cmp(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cmp.1.html) & [diff(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) which you might also use on the output of [od(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/od.1.html) or of  `hd`. And don't be so sure that your program is good.

Comment: I've just said that I am sure, cuz it works for even bigger ammounts of numbers, why would it crash here :D

Comment: You are a newbie to be so sure....

Comment: I completely fail to see why such an elaborate question with your 96-bit numbers, and your assembly, and the enormity of the files, and the screenshots, when at the end of the day you simply want to ask how to do a hex dump in linux, in which case, simply googling for "linux hex dump" yields a ton of results.

Comment: Would you like to hexdump that big file? I alreadygot `mcview` for that, but I cannot scroll down file like this, cuz I will mess up

Comment: When we speak of "hexdump" we do not mean "open in an editor that supports hexdump view".  We mean "pipe it through a program that will give you new text file containing a hex dump of the original file". So, the idea is very simple: if you can't easily compare two binary files in linux, (whereas there may even be ways to do that, but suppose there isn't,) then all you need to do is to have each binary file hexdumped into a text file and then run an ascii diff on the text files.

Comment: Okay, I know that. And I actually did that. But comparing ASCII characters will give me nothing, I wanted to compare bytes, which differ, and I cannot see which actually do

Comment: i think you didn't understand Mike right. do this: `hexdump file1.bin > file1.dat; hexdump file2.bin > file2.dat; diff file1.dat file2.dat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hexdump shows you the single bytes in big endian order. If a bunch of bytes have to be interpreted as a number, only the byte order is reversed.

```
little endian                           big endian (C notation)
AB CD EF                              = 0xEFCDAB
01 02 03 04  05 06 07 08  09 10 11 12 = 0x121110090807060504030201
```

Let's translate your examples to big endian order:

```
0x000000008100000000000000
0x000000007F00000000000000
```

You can see that the first number is bigger.

"Two's complement number" is not a very clear expression. Better is "signed integer". The sign which shows whether the number is positive or negativ, is the very first bit of the number. This bit can be found at the begginning of a big endian number and the end of a little endian number.

**Positive:**

```
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 00 = 0x000000008100000000000000
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 10 = 0x100000008100000000000000
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 7F = 0x7F0000008100000000000000
```

**Negativ:**

```
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 80 = 0x800000008100000000000000
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 CD = 0xCD0000008100000000000000
00 00 00 00  00 00 00 81  00 00 00 F0 = 0xF00000008100000000000000
```